# Installing spotlights but hole in ceiling is too big

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I bought 4 of these bad boys which I want to attach to my concrete ceiling (Oriel Baril LED Adjustable Spotlight). They are pretty lightweight.

[image]

Mounting cup diameter is 80mm

[image]

However, the mounting cup internal bracket screw hole distance is just 46mm

[image]

Here's the snag: The ceiling hole diameter is 60mm and too wide, so I'm missing some ceiling to screw into. With this width I can only get a single screw in.

[image]

What are my options?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Usually you'd attach the mounting bracket to the box or something else with some degree of structural strength *in* the ceiling and not to the ceiling itself. Does that round box have any mounting holes somewhere we can't see?

Comment: That looks like drywall mud more than concrete. If you shave it away inside the box do you find screw holes?

Comment: Where is your neutral wire? Is this setup using ground as return?

Comment: Yes, the plastic mounting cup in the ceiling has two screw holes. One is covered by plaster and can easily by cleaned up. The ceiling IS concrete even though the photo contains some plaster residue, but that is just around / inside the hole

Comment: @harper yes, there is a neutral wire which is just looped back to the other lights in the same area

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be a couple mounting holes in the junction box in the ceiling, but they look like they're covered in plaster. I'm not sure how there was a light here before (if there was) but anyway, you'll have to figure out where the mounting holes are.

Here's what the box looks like without all the plaster in the way:

[image: junction box mounted in ceiling]

You can probably look or reach into the box (*with the power off!*) to find them, then either drill or chip out the plaster so you can get at the mounting holes.

Next, screw the mounting strap into the box. You'll have to remove it from the light fixture first. Here's one with the same style mounting strap (but different style of fixture):

[image: strap being mounted to ceiling]

It looks to me the sizing is correct, but if it's not, you can get adapters to allow different spacings to be used.

[image: light fixture adapter] [image: light fixture adapters]

Comment: Thanks gregmac. This seems like the ideal solution. The mounting junction in the ceiling has two screw holes, one is just covered up by plaster. I'll clean it up and follow your advice.Thanks again for such a great answer with photos. It's a no brainer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what gregmac said. but if the box on the fixture is smaller than the mounting box hole, you can use a medallion to cover the gap. There are many sizes and shapes and are paintable. They can be found at any hardware or lighting store.